# Fetching all the cross sell product using rest api

Tags: magento2, rest-api, cross-sells

Is their any rest api available for fetching all the cross sell product ? By using the below mentioned api we can fetch only cross sell product against a particular sku. But I want all the the products that are cross product of some particular product.

```
/V1/products/{sku}/links/{type}
```

Comment: I think you need to create custom api for that. There is no readymade api available for your requirement.